Zuul dependency and Configuration issue
I have this zuul configuration which was working fine on Java 11 but and springboot 2.7.1.
I'm in the process of upgrading the project from java 11 to java 17 and to springboot 3.1.6 but I am getting this
Parameter 0 of method zuulPostProcessor in com.xxx.xx.xx required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.RouteLocator' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.RouteLocator' in your configuration.
I've tried adding dependencies, but nothing is working.
Sharing the snippet of code and pom.
@Bean
    public ZuulPostProcessor zuulPostProcessor(@Autowired RouteLocator routeLocator, @Autowired ZuulController zuulController,
            @Autowired(required = false) ErrorController errorController) {
        return new ZuulPostProcessor(routeLocator, zuulController, errorController);
    }

    private static final class ZuulPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

        private final RouteLocator routeLocator;

        private final ZuulController zuulController;

        private final boolean hasErrorController;

        ZuulPostProcessor(RouteLocator routeLocator, ZuulController zuulController, ErrorController errorController) {
            this.routeLocator = routeLocator;
            this.zuulController = zuulController;
            this.hasErrorController = (errorController != null);
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (hasErrorController && (bean instanceof ZuulHandlerMapping)) {
                Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
                enhancer.setSuperclass(ZuulHandlerMapping.class);
                enhancer.setCallbackFilter(LookupHandlerCallbackFilter.INSTANCE); // only for lookupHandler
                enhancer.setCallbacks(new Callback[] { LookupHandlerMethodInterceptor.INSTANCE, NoOp.INSTANCE });
                Constructor<?> ctor = ZuulHandlerMapping.class.getConstructors()[0];
                return enhancer.create(ctor.getParameterTypes(), new Object[] { routeLocator, zuulController });
            }
            return bean;
        }

    }

